# why orWhere Operator not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my code i want to search by product_name and merchant_name but when i use orWhere operator i get this error

BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orWhere does not exist. in file /Users/admin/Desktop/GSM Source Code/API/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php on line 113

```
 public function search($name)
{

    $brand = Brand::join('product_categories','product_categories.id','=','brands.category')
    ->join('products','products.id','=','brands.product')
    ->join('merchants','merchants.id','=','brands.merchant')
    ->join('new_shops','new_shops.id','=','brands.shop')
    ->get([
        'brands.id',
        'brands.image',
        'product_categories.category',
        'products.product_name',
        'merchants.merchant_name',
        'new_shops.shop_name',
        'brands.activation',
        'brands.created_at',
        'brands.updated_at'
    ])->where('product_name',$name)
    ->orWhere('merchant_name',$name);

    return new BrandResource($brand);

}
```

Also when i use LIKE operator in the where clause it doesnot not give any result

Comment: You can't user `orWhere` after `get` method. Because once you call get it turns query to collection and you are trying to call `orWhere` on collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use where and orWhere after get, like this:

```
$brand = Brand::join('product_categories','product_categories.id','=','brands.category')
    ->join('products','products.id','=','brands.product')
    ->join('merchants','merchants.id','=','brands.merchant')
    ->join('new_shops','new_shops.id','=','brands.shop')
     ->where('product_name',$name)
    ->orWhere('merchant_name',$name)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`orWhere` is a  QueryBuilder method. If you use `get` you are returning a collection which means you cannot use it. Try putting them before the get and should work well